# How can I control @Provider in JAX-RS runtime

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

I'm using a customised ContextResolver with my JAX-RS application.

```java
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver
    implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        super();
        // I want to control this
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME, true);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> type) {
        return objectMapper;
    }

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
}
```

As you can see, there is an option(`MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME`) customised.

How can I turn off that option on demand in JAX-RS resources?

```java
@Path("/items")
public class ItemsResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({APPLICATION_JSON, APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response read(@QueryParam("wrap") final boolean wrap) {
        if (wrap) {
            // turn off MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME
            // and then return response of [Items]
        } else {
            // turn on MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME
            // and then return response of [List<Item>]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to be injected with the provider?

Comment: It's possible to get the `ObjectMapper` through `@Context Providers`. For example `ObjectMapper mapper = providers.getContextResolver(ObjectMapper.class, mediaType).getContext(..);`. But configuration of the `ObjectMapper` [is not thread safe](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQThreadSafety). Sure you can create has a request scoped context resolver, but you need to think about performance with regards to this.

Comment: I haven't found much related to this, but you can check out [this](http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/jax-rs-jacksonjsonprovider-thread-safety-issues) and [this](http://markmail.org/message/gvmgpomvkmm5b5hm) for some discussion